# Hashcode/Equals override with number range rather than direct equals?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

Let's say I have an object that has a number range as two properties, a start and an end to define a numeric band. I want to load these objects into a HashMap. But when I look up on the hashcode and equals with a key object, I want to match on a given number that falls into the range. So I want the hashcode and equals to take any number in a key, and return the object where it falls between the startRange and endRange. So if an object has a startRange of 7 and endRange of 14, passing 9 in a key would retrieve that object. How do I do this? The equals would be straightforward as I would use >= and <=, but I don't want to break the hashcode... I know I can iterate item by item but I'd like to avoid that for performance reasons.

```
public class MyClass {
private final int marketID;
private final int startRange;
private final int endRange;
...

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + marketID;
    /*I don't want to match on startRange and endRange, I want to fall between it! */
    result = prime * result + endRange; 
    result = prime * result + startRange;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    if (endRange!= other.endRange)
        return false;
    if (marketID != other.marketID)
        return false;
    if (startRange!= other.startRange)
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Use a `TreeMap`, not a `HashMap`.  It has methods for this kind of thing.

Comment: Okay awesome... if I have to make this threadsafe, can I use a ConcurrentSkipMap to accomplish this too?

Comment: I don't see why not.  Why don't you try it?

Comment: Are you building up a histogram or bucket sorting? For those, the trick is you do the math *before* accessing the map, so something like ```map.get(value / 10)```

Comment: With `TreeMap` you will keep the order of elements that you add to it, but the problem is that you can't override the equals (more correctly contains method) to check if that element contains (between some range) and after all retrieve that element in constant time. What you're looking up in a hash table (any map) is the instance signature of the object and not their values. So, you can't avoid iterating the keys for performance reasons.